# Is there an expression in English for saying "to make your own mistakes"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

In Russian, we say "to have one's bumps" when we mean that someone makes their own mistakes, thus getting experience and learning from their errors. Is there anything similar to that in English?

Comment: I think it's more AmE than BrE, but Anglophones say you've got to [***take** your **lumps***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22got+to+take+your+lumps%22) for "put up with troubles without complaining". It doesn't really have the same "learning" implications as saying you went to [*the school of hard knocks*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22at+the+school+of+hard+knocks%22)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word or phrase describing a painful learning experience](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562889/word-or-phrase-describing-a-painful-learning-experience) Also related: [a word for someone who has been through a lot of hardship and is therefore not naive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372696/word-for-someone-who-has-been-through-a-lot-of-hardship-and-is-therefore-not-na%c3%af/372852#372852).

Comment: **Pay your dues**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English you can say "Let him learn **the hard way**". It means, let him learn by making mistakes *and suffering the consequences*.

> You can take my advice and not overfill your automatic transmission with fluid, or you can learn the hard way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!